# How to Detect Memory leaks for Qt windows desktop application, using QtCreator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, memory, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory leak checking on Windows with QT and MinGW32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527325/memory-leak-checking-on-windows-with-qt-and-mingw32)

I have looked for a solution to this problem for a while, and have not been able to find anything. I need to be able to detect small memory leaks in my Qt application, which I develop in QtCreator. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825376/how-to-detect-memory-leaks-in-qtcreator-on-windows) talks about detecting Qt memory leaks in Qt applications, but not through QtCreator. I would run my application on a linux machine and use Valgrind, but I have some windows specific stuff in it, so it's not fully portable. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What toolchain do you use? mingw-gcc or vc?

Comment: In run/debug menu there should be option "debug with valgrind" or something like this. valgrind is memory profiling tool. It should be helpful when searching for memory leaks

Comment: @KamilKlimek I know what Valgrind is, but Valgrind is only for mac/linux...

Comment: I didn't know mingw hasn't port valgrind. Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows it may become very helpfull